# Crystal report the details section in subreport is not displaying in main report

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I am adding a subreport in the main report "Page footer" section.

In my subreport field and text object in report header which displayed correctly. I also put field in details section which is not diplaying.

I am sure my query contains data.

Anybody has idea what do I need to do?

Thanks so much

Comment: Does the query generated by crystal fetching any data? Check that against database

Comment: Does your data contains more than one table? May you improve the description of your design? I did not understand.

Comment: Have you linked the main report and subreport??